# Identify accounts not active for 2 years

Tags: sql, oracle

Below given is the sample of my dataset
[image: transaction data for 3 years]

For 2017 at daily level I need to identify those accounts which did not do any transaction in last two years and flag them as 1.

What could be the best way to code row by row for 2017 year looking back two years dataset in SQL Oracle

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Update your question add  the table schema .. a proper data sample  and the expetced  result  ..but text . no image  ..

Comment: Two years ago is `add_months(sysdate, -24)`. Looks like you want rows where trade_date is less than that.

Answer (score 0):

This query identifies accounts where the most recent trade was more than two years ago:

```
select client_id
         , account_no
         , max(trade_date) as last_active 
from your_table
group by client_id
         , account_no
having max(trade_date)  < add_months(sysdate, -24)
```

Comment: This wont work as sysdate would take 2018 date as current date. We are looking for 2015-17 data

Comment: Well substitute `date '2017-12-31' for `sysdate`

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE dataset
SET FLAG = 1 
WHERE TRADE_DATE < (TRADE_DATE - 730) --(day)
AND FLAG <> 1;
```

OR

```
UPDATE dataset
SET FLAG = 1 
WHERE TRADE_DATE < ADD_MONTH(TRADE_DATE,-24) --(month)
AND FLAG <> 1;
```

Comment: `TRADE_DATE < (TRADE_DATE) - 730` is always false

Comment: Your edit is still pointless.  In both cases you have `( X )   <   ( X - <something> )` which is always false.  What do you ***think*** this is meant to be doing???

Comment: @MatBailie, looking at their profile pic I think they might be a bit new to this... :) (no offense intended)